# Is there anyway for VS or ReSharper to make my methods "inherit" '///' documentation from the super class?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I really don't want to have to copy the XML method documentation tags from my interfaces or base classes to the hundreds of inheriting types.  Can VS or Resharper do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into GhostDoc. http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx